# Printing A PDF in vb.net doesn't work 100% the time

Tags: vb.net

All,

I have the following code that I'm using to print pdf files written to disk:

```
Public Function PrintPDF(ByVal PDFFile As String, ByVal Printer As String, ByVal Timeout As Integer) As Integer

    log_error.sendEventLog("PrintPDF", "DEBUGGING - Printing PDF. File: " & PDFFile & ". Printer: " & Printer, EventLogEntryType.Information)

    If Printer.Trim.Length = 0 Then
        Printer = (New System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings).PrinterName
    End If

    Dim Proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process

    Try
        Proc.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        Proc.StartInfo.FileName = PDFFile
        Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = Chr(34) + Printer + Chr(34)
        Proc.StartInfo.Verb = "PrintTo"
        Proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
        Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True

        Proc.Start()
    Catch ex As Exception
        log_error.sendEventLog("PrintPDF Error", "An issue has occured when attemtping to print a PDF", EventLogEntryType.Error)
    End Try

    Do While Timeout > 0 AndAlso Not Proc.HasExited
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Timeout -= 1
    Loop

    If Not Proc.HasExited Then
        log_error.sendEventLog("PrintPDF", "Process Killed", EventLogEntryType.Information)
        Proc.Kill()
    End If

    log_error.sendEventLog("PrintPDF", "Process Closed", EventLogEntryType.Information)
    Proc.Close()
    Proc.Dispose()

    Return 0
End Function
```

When utilizing this method, I'm looping through around 10 PDF documents.  These documents range anywhere between 2mb and 5mb.  For one reason or another some of the documents print and others do not.  There isn't a correlation, it seems, between file size and printing success.  No errors are being thrown as this is processing.

Has anyone run into issues before like this?  Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I found out that if I increase the sleep time then the thread has time to finish what it doing and then print the PDF. Try that hope it helps